# static local variable and static local object initialization

Tags: c++

In VC++2008  there is a serious difference in initialization of  static local variable and static local object.  Static local variable is  initialized  before main() and  its definition statement within the function is skipped.  Static local object is  initialized  by  0 value  before main() and  its definition statement within the function is executed only once . Constructor is started  and object is  initialized  by appropiate value. All that can be seen in Debug mode. Does this solution correspond to the existing C++ Standard?

Comment: Please post the exact code in concern.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf :

> Every object of static storage
>   duration shall be zero-initialized at
>   program startup before any other
>   initialization takes place. [ Note: in
>   some cases, additional initialization
>   is done later. —end note ]